# Make a searchable volume in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, find

I need to put the contents of a Volume in a mysql database, to be searchable via a web interface.

To get all the files/folders, I can do:

```
$ cd /Volumes/myVolume
$ find ./
```

Which will give me all I need to know.

If my mysql table only has one column called `path`, what would be the most efficient way to write all the paths to the table, given there are 1M+ paths.

Comment: mysql has tools to do this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the output of the script above to a file and then import the file.

Run the following:

```
find ./ > directorylisting.txt
```

Open the file and see how to import it into MySQL using one of the many import functions available. The link daniph mentioned in the comment on your question has some links. You can use the mysqlimport or `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to load this file into the table. Index it properly and you should be well away.